# Color problem in Terminal (Mojave)

Tags: terminal

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.5 and I'm having color problems when accessing a CentOS workstation.

Initially, after connecting via `ssh`, I would obtain the following welcome message:

[image]

Then I added the following commands to the bash file:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and I commented the following line in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
# SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

After all this the welcome message I get is without errors but still distorted:

[image]

What i should get is the following (i got it using iTerm2 3.2.9):

[image]

How can I fix the colors? The command that prints "virgo-cluster" is:

```
figlet -f slant virgo-cluster | lolcat -t
```

Comment: you would need to include an example of the lines the print 'virgo cluster', in order to see how they may need to be changed to work on all envs.

Comment: @NewAlexandria hi, I added the command at the end of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the odd behavior is due to the fact that Terminal.app does not support True Color (16 million colors), while iTerm2 3.2.9 does. Here the result of a test code from [here](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728):

[image]

the top panel is from Terminal while the bottom one is from iTerm.